# Does ExecuteMultipleRequest work in Outlook offline mode?

Tags: outlook, offline, dynamics-crm-2016

I have a plugin  ex:which updates all its child records when that is updated.

This plugin is registered to execute in offline mode as well.

I have done this using ExecuteMultipleRequest. This is working fine when I am updating the parent record from CRM instance.

When I go offline and try to update the parent record its throwing business process error "executemultiplemaxbatchsize".

I checked the exception with Debugging it is as below.

**System.NotImplementedException: Microsoft Dynamics CRM has experienced an error. Reference number for administrators or support: #ABA895C7**

**Does ExecuteMultipleRequest work in Outlook offline mode?**

As per MSDN link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.messages.executemultiplerequest.aspx
it says
This message works regardless whether the caller is connected to the server or offline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the SDK documentation it should but I think that is typo in the documentation. You can open a ticket with Microsoft and they'll probably correct the documentation but not change the functionality.

The reason I believe it's a documentation is is that there is NO reason to use `ExecuteMultipleRequest` in a plugin. Since there is no SOAP overhead or latency - because the plugin is running on the server and does not use the Organization.svc endpoint - you don't gain any benefit from using `ExecuteMultipleRequest` in a plugin. `ExecuteMultipleRequest` is intended for use in client applications to improve performance, not for plugins and workflows.